# Latin scientific phrase for during, outside, non and never intervention

Tags: idiom, scientific-names

What is a scientific way of saying, in Latin,

- During Intervention
- Outside of Intervention
- Never received Intervention.
- Missing Intervention.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Your question has been put on hold for insufficient context. If you edit your question to elaborate on it, it can be reopened. Please consult [this meta page for instructions for asking a translation question if you don't know much Latin](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/483/79) and follow all the instructions given there. The more you add, the better we will be able to help you. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What kind o of intervention do you have in mind?

Comment: @Rafael, "financial" intervention

Comment: Thanks! You may want to put that into the question's body. And a brief explanation, examples, and/or a link or two to definitions would also be welcome. It'll be reopen for sure! :) It's just that word-by-word translations are usually less correct than those made with the context in mind